# What's wrong with my ASP.NET / Visual Basic code?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services, asmx

I'm new to ASP.NET / Visual basic. I'm trying to create a simple get request to get the data from the database. But whenever the page loads, I get a generic 500 server error code in the console. Here is my ASP.NET code:

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <script>
        var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({ transport: {
                                read:  {
                                        url: "/webservices/alertService.asmx/GetAlert",
                                        dataType: "json"
                                        },
                                update: {
                                        url: "/webservices/alertService.asmx/UpdateAlert",
                                        dataType: "json"
                                        }
                         }});
        var alertObj = dataSource.read();
        console.log("alertObj: ", alertObj);
        var pageBody = document.getElementById('page-body');
        
        pageBody.innerHTML = "<h1>Website alert page is currently being built...</h1><br/>" +
                             "<p>" + alertObj.alert_title + "</p><br/>"  +
                             "<p>" + alertObj.alert_body + "</p><br/>"  
    </script> 

    <div id="page-body"></div>

</asp:content>
```

Here is my Visual Basic code:

```
<%@ WebService Language="VB" Class="MapService" %>

Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Security
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization
Imports System.Web.Script.Services
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.Xml.Serialization
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.Odbc
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data.Sql
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Imports System.Net.Http

<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
<System.Web.Services.WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
<System.Web.Services.WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<ToolboxItem(False)> _
Public Class MapService
Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

<WebMethod()> _
Public Sub GetAlert()
    Dim xmlString As String = ""

    Try
        Dim sConnString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("WebApp").ConnectionString
        Dim odbcConn As OdbcConnection = New OdbcConnection(sConnString)
    
        Dim sQueryString As String = "SELECT * FROM tblalert WHERE alert_id = 1"
        Dim DBCommand As New OdbcCommand(sQueryString, odbcConn)
        odbcConn.Open()

        Try

            Dim odbcReader As OdbcDataReader = DBCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
            While odbcReader.Read()
    
                xmlString += "{"
                xmlString += """alert_id"":""" & Convert.ToInt16(odbcReader("alert_id")) & ""","
                xmlString += """alert_title"":""" & Trim(odbcReader("alert_title").ToString) & ""","
                xmlString += """alert_body"":""" & Trim(odbcReader("alert_body").ToString) & ""","
                xmlString += """show_alert"":""" & Convert.ToInt16(odbcReader("show_alert")) & ""","
                xmlString += "}"

            End While

            odbcReader.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception

            odbcConn.Close()

        End Try

        odbcConn.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

    'xmlString = xmlString.Trim().Substring(0, xmlString.Length - 1)
    'xmlString = "[" & xmlString & "]"

    HttpContext.Current.Response.BufferOutput = True
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/x-javascript"
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(xmlString)
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush()

End Sub
```

What is wrong with my code? Why is the "dataSource.read()" function not getting the data from the VB file?

Comment: You need to debug the service and see where it errors and what the error details are. Also you have tagged the question with c# and vba, both not applicable to this question.

Comment: Thanks for updating the tags. I don't know how to debug the service. I do think the issue is with the visual basic part of the code based on the tests I've run to try to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized I put the wrong VB function in the question. I just edited it and added the right function "GetAlert()"

Comment: If you are going to be a programmer you have to learn to debug. At minimum, you can put code in your `catch` blocks that at least logs what the error is. But, it is simple enough, click inside the catch block, press F9 to set a break point and then press F5 to run with debugger. Recreate the error and you will break in your code. Learn to debug!

Comment: 1) You could comment out the `Try`s and `Catch`es, and note that an empty `Catch` is usually a bad idea as that prevents it from telling you what went wrong. 2) Incidentally, it is important to give variables appropriate names: using "xmlString" for something formatted as JSON is misleading.

Comment: Learning to debug code is a critical skill. There's [lots of documentation for how to do it in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2019).

Comment: @AndrewMorton I tried that and it did not work. Would you be able to create an answer with a simple get request in ASP.NET and VB?

I literally just need to get the object stored in the database table "tblalert". There's only one row in the table

Comment: @user13989216 Unfortunately "did not work" does not tell us enough to be able to write something that would work. We need to know what error message it gives - you could look in the Windows event logs (the Application one) to get the error message.

Comment: This is not a debugging  issue.  the syntax of the request doesn't meet the server requirements.  You have to check the server documentation to determine why your request is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

According to this web-site http://net-informations.com/q/mis/500.html the problem is on your server side.  Something isn't configured correctly.  Double check the connection string you are using to make sure it is connecting to the right server and then check to make sure the server is running and accessible.